# How to get two different records from RAND()?

Tags: php, sql

I am making an exercise related app. My plans are for day A and day B. I have a database with a list of exercises in it. When I try to search for a given exercise, it is drawn for day A. But when I try to draw it for day B, it happens that the two are the same data. I tried to compare these two data, but I still fail.

```
$e_legs_B = "SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE body_part = 'Quad' AND difficulty = 'Easy' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$e_legs_B_run = mysqli_query($conn, $e_legs_B);
```

Then in body my code looks like this.

```
<?php
$rows = $e_legs_B_run->fetch_assoc();
$name = $rows['name'];
echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>";
?>
```

Comment: You need to store the already-used exercises somewhere and remove them for the second query.

Comment: What does  `$e_legs_A` look like?

Comment: @GMB same like $e_legs_B

Answer (score 0):

Select data for day a and b in one query and split the result.

Or store the id's from day a in an array and exclude them in the second query for day b.

Comment: I increased the limit of RAND to 2 and now it works. Thanks